# Dealing with stack as struct element in cpp

Tags: c++, struct, stl, stack

I was working on a project recently and stumbled upon following situation

```
using namespace std;

//I have two structs, A basic struct as shown below
struct myAnotherStruct{
  int x;
  int y;
};

//A struct which embeds the stack of above struct type
struct myStruct{
  int a;
  float b;
  stack <myAnotherStruct> s;
};

//Somewhere else in the code, I created this
stack <myStruct> t;

//And performed following
struct myAnotherStruct var;
var.x = 10;
var.y = 20;

// But, when I performed the following operation, there was a core Dump!
t.s.push(var)
```

Now, My question are the following,

1. Why core dump? should'nt the memory be allocated every time I add a new element? the var should be copied and storage class of the variable (var in my case) should not matter!
2. Is it a good approach to do something like this? Because when I googled, I always got "stack of structs, Vector of structs" etc but not the other way (I.e, Struct of stacks).

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. `t.s.push(var)` wouldn’t compile because `stack <myStruct> t` has no member `s`.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a stack of `myStruct` and not a `myStruct` instance.

```
//Somewhere else in the code, I created this
stack <myStruct> t;
```

You need to change it to:

```
myStruct t;
```

In the original code, the compiler should generate an error since `stack` has no member `s` here:

```
// But, when I performed the following operation, there was a core Dump!
t.s.push(var)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you attempt to access an element of the stack without pushing an item to the stack like so:

```cpp
myStruct m;  // Creates new myStruct object 
t.push(m);   // Adds object to stack
```

Furthermore the `.` operator does not automatically get the top object in the stack. If you want to add `var` to the member variable `s` in `t`, consider using `t.top().s.push(var);` to get the top element of the stack and then push car to the stack.